# How do you call other internal methods from inside a javascript closure with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, closures

Here is my example object to demonstrate the issue.

```
Dog = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
    },
    Speak: function (sayThis) {
        console.log(sayThis);
    },
    CallInternalSpeak: function () {
        this.Speak("arf! from internal function.");
    },
    CallSpeakFromClosure: function () {

        this.Speak("arf! fron outside closure.");

        var callClosure = function () {  // think of this closure like calling jquery .ajax and trying to call .Speak in your success: closure
            console.log("we get inside here fine");
            this.Speak("say hi fron inside closure.");  // THIS DOES NOT WORK
        }

        callClosure();
    }
});

var rover = new Dog;

rover.Speak("arf! from externally called function");
rover.CallInternalSpeak();
rover.CallSpeakFromClosure();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in Backbone, you can always use Underscore's bind function as well.  After you define callClosure, you can wrap it with a proper binding:

```
callClosure = _.bind(callClosure, this);
```

Comment: does that go here?  I can't seem to get it to work:  initialize: function () {
        callClosure = _.bind(callClosure, this);
    },

Comment: What is your error?  Is Underscore.js being referenced in your example?  I assume it is because you are working with Backbone... but I thought I'd make sure.

Comment: Oh, and fancy meeting you here, Shane :)

Comment: ah yes, that works.  I was trying to call _.bind from initialize.  And yes, how you doing Brian.  Who knew you were so prolific on SO.  :)  So i'm assuming this autobind thing is NOT a good idea?  Just bind what you need only?  http://grenzgenial.com/post/7356697292/binding-this-automatically-in-backbone-js

Comment: I certainly prefer binding only when you need it.  I really like CoffeeScript when working with Backbone and binding is built into the language (-> vs =>) and the opinion there is bind when you need to.

Comment: oh, and one last clarification. what do you mind to if you don't have an object, if you are calling something like $.ajax?   UpdateMessagesCount: function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Messages/GetMessagesCount/',
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (NewMessagesCount) {

                // what about in here?
            }
        });
    },

Answer (score 1):

The old "self" trick... make a reference to this, call it self, and reference it in the function.

```
CallSpeakFromClosure: function () {

    this.Speak("arf! fron outside closure.");
    var self = this;

    var callClosure = function () {  
        console.log("we get inside here fine");
        self.Speak("say hi fron inside closure.");  // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    }

    callClosure();
}
```

Comment: I tried the self trick and that worked.  How about the backbone way?  Is that the underscore bind?  I just can't seem to get that syntax right.

Comment: Well, Backbone.js brings in Underscore.js as a dependency (think Linq for js... kind of) for a lot of base functionality.  http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods

Comment: Here is Backbone's FAQ about your specific problem: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this